# How to have multicolumn with each cell being multiple rows with everything centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, layout

I am trying to achieve this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vitae accumsan ligula. Aenean vel condimentum magna. Aenean in nisi sed sem semper molestie. Donec ac pulvinar tellus. Nunc sollicitudin ac enim hendrerit fermentum. Nulla dapibus tempus tempus. Proin sit amet tellus euismod, bibendum quam in, ornare arcu. Vivamus lobortis, ex id cursus gravida, lorem felis laoreet risus, nec gravida tortor velit sit amet est.

       * * * * ** ** * * * *     * * * * ** ** * * * *    * * * * ** ** * * * * 
       Hello World               Hello World              Hello World           
       * * * * ** ** * * * *     * * * * ** ** * * * *    * * * * ** ** * * * * 

       * * * * ** ** * * * *     * * * * ** ** * * * *    * * * * ** ** * * * * 
       Hello World               Hello World              Hello World           
       * * * * ** ** * * * *     * * * * ** ** * * * *    * * * * ** ** * * * * 

       * * * * ** ** * * * *     * * * * ** ** * * * *    * * * * ** ** * * * * 
       Hello World               Hello World              Hello World           
       * * * * ** ** * * * *     * * * * ** ** * * * *    * * * * ** ** * * * * 

   ...

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vitae accumsan ligula. Aenean vel condimentum magna. Aenean in nisi sed sem semper molestie. Donec ac pulvinar tellus. Nunc sollicitudin ac enim hendrerit fermentum. Nulla dapibus tempus tempus. Proin sit amet tellus euismod, bibendum quam in, ornare arcu. Vivamus lobortis, ex id cursus gravida, lorem felis laoreet risus, nec gravida tortor velit sit amet est.
```

Where the `* ... Hello World ... *` stuff is verbatim text of unknown width (i.e. it is the width of the content), which stretches over multiple *rows*, and there are multiple of them per row (3 in this case, since 3 fit nicely with a gap on the sides).

Basically I would like to do this:

```
% first row
\centering
\begin{table}
  \begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
  \end{verbatim}

  \gap

  \begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
  \end{verbatim}

  \gap

  \begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
  \end{verbatim}
\end{table}

% second row
\centering
\begin{table}
  \begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
  \end{verbatim}

  \gap

  \begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
  \end{verbatim}

  \gap

  \begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
  \end{verbatim}
\end{table}
```

Wondering how to accomplish that.

Comment: Have you tried [Excel2Latex](https://www.heise.de/download/product/excel2latex-66332)?
I know that is not really what you asked, but it could help you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using a table with columns of the `p` type and a specific size. Within these columns you can insert `verbatim` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth}p{0.33\textwidth} }
\begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
\end{verbatim} &
\begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
\end{verbatim} &
\begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
\end{verbatim} \\
\begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
\end{verbatim} &
\begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
\end{verbatim} &
\begin{verbatim}
* * * * ** ** * * * *
Hello World          
* * * * ** ** * * * *
\end{verbatim} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit:** Removed table borders

Comment: Wondering how to remove the borders, would like it without the borders.

Comment: @LancePollard The vertical borders can be removed by removing the `|` characters from the `\begin{tabular}` command. The horizontal borders can be removed by removing the individual `\hline` commands, that print the lines.

Comment: @LancePollard I have edited the answer and removed all the borders